# New dragon shouts learnt from word walls are not appearing in shout list

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have learnt a couple of new words but they are not appearing in my shout list. Does anyone have an idea why this is? I am supposed to use the Bend Will shout but it's not on my Shouts list, so I can't use it on the Wind Stone.

Comment: What do you mean with "I have learnt a couple of new shout words"? Do you mean the word appeared on your screen temporarily (like all other shouts)? And what shouts don't work for you?

Comment: And are you using any mods?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug.

Try reloading a save before you attempted to learn this shout and try again.

Additionally, verifying integrity of game files could be of assistance in case any changes to the files or incidents within caused the bug.

Comment: Thanks. I have done that on numerous occasions and still doesn't work.  I thought maybe someone may know.

Comment: How so I verify integrity of the files on ps4

Comment: @SharonMareeBall That's a Steam feature. If you're on PS4 you can reinstall the game, but I doubt there is a problem with the files, as under normal circumstances they shouldn't have been touched.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment on MalO's answer I presume you're on PS4, but for those playing on PC, you can use the console command `player.teachword <wordID>`, with the ID for *Bend Will* being `xx0179d8`.